# Best complexity for synchronizing a map with a collection

Tags: java, android, algorithm, collections

I have the following problem for which I would like a decent solution.

I have a HashMap that contains some objects in the form of String(email) and object(Person). 
This map is populated via a collection via a method **updatePersonList(Collection list**) as described below: 

Every time a new collection is received via the above method the map will basically add all the elements from the collection to the map. That is all the map needs, the latest collection. What is not in the collection should be discarded from the map.

Now, I want to know how can I update efficiently the map because, as it can be read above it is possible to have the following scenarios : 
1. Some objects can be found in both the map and the collection, therefore, only the new objects from the collection should be kept and not all.
2. Objects that are in the map but are not in the collection should be removed.

What is the best solution in terms of complexity?

After some investigation I came with the remove of all the objects from the map and add the ones from the collection. If someone knows something better would be nice if it can be shared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will never get better than **O(n+m)** where n is the size of your `Collection` and m is the size of your `Map` because you will always need to read at least both ones.

So in **O**-notation you could simply erase the hole `Map` and create a new one.

But in reality the constant might be not so unimportant and you also may want to reduce garbage collection. In this cases it might make sense to iterate through both and only delete the needed entries from the Map and add the new elements from the Collection to the Map.

But only profiling will tell you if you gained anything for that effort.

Comment: That is what I was thinking about, because, as far as I know, when removing data, the map will shrink and reduce its size and during add it will resize after adding data. This may not be so memory-performant. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Andrei T: because elements in the Map are removed and new ones are created there will be more garbage → more often a garbage collection if you remove the hole map and create a new one. But if this has noticeable  impact in your app you can only tell after comparing both implementations and profiling them.

Answer (score 0):

According to my point of view Use Treemap instead of list to improve your iteration performance i.e (Treemap will take only unique values) so that newly inserted objects will identify automatically

After succesfully design treemap don't remove markers on the map instead add news markers which will define in treemap

i hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

If list has often the same content as map you can check it before cleaning the map and adding new entries.